# I'm planning to visit Turkey for sightseeing. Do I need an eVisa or do I need to visit the embassy?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, europe, turkey

I live in Krakow. I have a valid Indian passport + EU blue card. I'm planning to visit Turkey for sightseeing. Do I need an eVisa or do I need to visit the embassy? Is there any restriction on choosing the airline [I remember I saw that one needs to select Turkish Airline]?

Do I need travel insurance?

Answer (score 1):

You are eligible to [apply for an e-Visa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/), per Turkey's [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa):

> **India**: Diplomatic passport holders are exempt from visa for their travels to Turkey up to 90 days. Ordinary, Special and Service passport holders are required to have visa to enter Turkey. Ordinary, Special and Service passport holders with a valid Schengen members or USA, UK, Ireland visa or residence permit may get their single entry e-Visas valid for one month via the website www.evisa.gov.tr, provided that they meet certain conditions.

While certain nationals must [travel to Turkey with specific airlines](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/are-there-any-restrictions-on-airline-companies-to-fly-to-turkey/), India is not among those restricted; you're free to select any carrier.